# How do I provide a search form for a specific post type, that is capable of searching within custom fields of the specified CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I'm building a site that will have four post types:
The default 'page' and 'post' post types. And two custom post types.

The two custom post types will have custom fields and custom taxonomies.

I'd like to provide three search forms: the default form (for 'page' and 'post' data), and one form for each of the custom post types.

For the post types 'page' and 'post', I can just use (or modify) get_search_form().

However, the default WordPress form doesn't list posts of custom types, and doesn't search custom field data.

So how do I provide this to my users: For each custom post type, a search form that will search only that type, and that will return results that include data from the custom fields of it's specific post type?

Comment: Search just uses WP_Query, so you could create custom page templates (for example) that query custom post types based on the search query string in the URL.

Comment: @NabhaCosley, sure. But I want to let users do searches based on phrases they are looking for. Forms are good for that, but by default they don't query cpt's. And if they are altered to include cpt's, they don't include custom field data. The best thing for the user is for me to provide search form for each CPT, capable of searching custom field data.

Comment: I think I understand, but maybe I should have explained more. WP_Query has a search field you can use. You should be able to use it in combination with a meta_query and filtering only a single custom post type. The forms can then send you to a page (or pages) with page template(s) that use WP_Query in that way. … or are you saying that the search doesn't search the custom field data? Sorry, I missed that. (I've used Relevanssi to fix that in the past, I don't know if that's an option for you, but I should mention it.)

Comment: This looks like a code option that you can adjust, to search post meta: https://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/